# Software to auto-tag text, such as blog post or news articles?

Tags: search, tags, full-text-search, stop-words

I am searching for a software that would do the following:

1. process numerous articles varying from 100-1k words;
2. automatically remove [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopwords);
3. recommend best tags based on remaining words, i.e. this article is all about "car, transmission, japan".

To me this is sort of like Google's internal keyword summary tools. Any idea? Will an open source full-text search tool like Ferret be a viable option? But I am totally open to commercial software tools as well.